# Lazy self-recursive data structures in Clojure

Tags: clojure

Is there a way to describe arbitrary lazy self-recursive data structures in Clojure?
Let's say for example I wanted to do something like this:

```
(def inf-seq (fn rec [] (lazy-seq (cons 42 (rec)))))
(take 3 (inf-seq))
```

but with a map:

```
(def inf-map (fn rec [] (??? {:a (rec) :b 42})))
(get-in (inf-map) [:a :a :a :b])
```

Comment: as a completely different approach, you could use Clojure and Frege in the same project and code your lazy recursive data structures in Frege, which is almost Haskell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sequence laziness does not apply to deferred function evaluation in Clojure, which you would obviously need for constructing infinitely nested maps.

Try using Delays:

```
user=> (def inf-map (fn rec [] {:a (delay (rec)) :b 42}))
#'user/inf-map
user=> (inf-map)
{:a #<Delay@4e9f9a19: :pending>, :b 42}
user=> @(:a (inf-map))
{:a #<Delay@5afd479c: :pending>, :b 42}
```

Comment: Also see (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542236/clojure-deferred-function-execution)